# Laravel: How to validate multiple size rules on same file based on mime-type

Tags: laravel, validation

Hello great people of SO!

I hope you all have a good day

I want to validate uploaded file based on their mime type

> if file is an image, **maximum size is 2Mb**

> if file is a video, **maximum size is 500Mb**

Atm, this is my code snippet

```
public function upload(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'file.*' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,mp4', 'max:2048'] // 2 Mb for images / photos, *but how to put maximum size for video?*
    ]);

    ...
}
```

As you can see, I put: `max:2048`, which is maximum size for an image

*I want to allow users, to upload video up to 500Mb*

> UPDATE

I can separate each file type based on their mimes on JavaScript

```
// Example: (Some snippet from my code)

var files = Array.prototype.slice.call(event.target.files)
    $formData = new FormData

    files.forEach((f, i) => {
        var fType = f.type.lowerCase()

        // or if you want to get file ext,
        // use this: f.name.substr(f.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, f.name[length - 1])
        // 'example_image.jpeg' > 'jpeg'
        // 'example_video.mp4' > 'mp4'

        // Here, we can validate the files
        // Example:

        // You can use regex here, but I prefer to use an array of string, so for future update, if I ever want to 'whitelist' new ext, I can easily add them to this array

        if (['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'].indexOf(fType) !== -1) {
            // File is an image with format: jpe?g / png
            
            if ((f.size / 1024) < 2048) {
                // Image size is less than 2Mb, valid
                $formData.append(['image[' + i + ']', f); // f is the file, see forEach above
            }
        }

        if (['video/mp4'].indexOf(fType) !== -1) {
            // File is a video
            if ((f.size / 1024) < 512000) {
                // Video size is less than 500 Mb, valid
                $formData.append(['video[' + i + ']'), f);
            }
        }

        // else: error (file is not an image / video)

        ... // XHR upload call
    })
```

Then, on server side, for validation

```
// I can separate the uploaded files
    
public function upload(Request $request) {

    // OBVIOUSLY 'this is NOT the best way to do it'
    $request->validate([
        'image.*' => ['file', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png', 'max:2048'],
        'video.*' => ['file', 'mimes:mp4', 'max:512000']
    ]);

    ..
}
```

If you want to know which index the error is:

```
// *NOTE* I'm using Vue & Axios here

Object.entries(exc.response.data.errors).forEach(([e, m]) => {
    // Error response would be:
        // image.0 => ['error message']
        // ...
        // video.3 => ['error message']

    var errorIndex = parseInt(e.split('.')[1])
        // image.0 > ["image", "0"]
        errorMsg = m[0]            

    // Since we stored all previous selected files in an array

    console.log(`Error in file index: ${errorIndex}, file name: ${this.upload.files[errorIndex].name}`)
    console.log(`Error message: ${errorMsg}`)

    // Error in file index [X], file name: hello_there.mp4
    // Error: video.X size cannot be more than ... kilobytes (500Mb)
})
```

But the thing is, I want to do it only with **Laravel way**

> Q: **How to put maximum size for video?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Best way is creating your own **Validation Rule**, assuming that you are using laravel 8: [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) @ChristianDelvianto

Comment: simplest way: pass a flag (like image=>1, video=>2 etc.). then add rules based on flag.

Comment: other options : (1.)add a after validation hook->guess mimetype->validate size based on mimetype. (2.) Create your own validation rule.

Comment: it's either image or video right? if yes then just need to add conditional validation 
for image and videos

Comment: Question updated

Comment: have my solution helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can validate based on file mime type like below psudo-code:

```
public function upload(Request $request) {
    $rules = [];

    $image_max_size = 1024 * 2;
    $video_max_size = 1024 * 500;

    foreach($request->file('file') as $index => $file){
        if(in_array($file->getMimeType(), ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png']) {
          $rules["file.$index"] = ["max:$image_max_size"];
        } else if (in_array($file->getMimeType(), ['video/mp4']){
          $rules["file.$index"] = ["max:$video_max_size"];
        } else {

          // Always non-validating => returns error
          $rules["file.$index"] = ['bail', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,mp4'];
        }
    }

    $request->validate($rules);

    ...
}
```

I had similar problem and make that solved using this approach.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I'm out of region rn, I will test your code tomorrow, and tell the result later, anyway thanks for trying to help me to solve the issue

Comment: Thanks for Accepting, Testing and Editing.

Answer (score -1):

try this =>

```
public function upload(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'file.*' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png', 'max:2048'],
        'file.mp4' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:mp4', 'max:512000'] // 500 Mb for video/ 
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but your solution is not working